# Adding Conversion events to a cloud message using Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, firebase-admin

I am able to send Push notifications using the code below but I am also required to associate "Conversion events" with the notification. This can be done through the console but I couldn't find how to do it with SDK.

```cs
var message = new Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "test1", "6165" },
                    { "test2", "161" },
                },
                Notification =
                {
                    Body = "",
                    Title = ""
                },
                Topic = topic,

            };
            // Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
            Task<string> response =  FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message, true);
            // Response is a message ID string.
            response.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```